# roscore can't be found

Tags: ros-melodic, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After installation  melodic in ubuntu 18.04 for first time,i input "roscore" in ubuntu terminal command port, i see as follows:

```
Command 'roscore' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install python-roslaunch
```

Is it right? If it's wrong,how to solve it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/347924/roscore-can%27t-be-found/) by [Dean](https://answers.ros.org/users/53030/dean/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2020-03-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you remember to first `source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash` before trying to run `roscore`?

---

Edit:

> ```
> sudo apt install ros-melodic-desktop-full
> ```
>
> There isn't roscore in `/home/my name/opt/ros/melodic/bin`, does it mean i didn't install successfully?
>
> http://wiki.ros.org/cn/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu

I would not expect it to be located in `$HOME`, but in `opt/ros/melodic/bin`.

What is the output of `ls -al /opt/ros/melodic/bin/roscore`? Do not change the path, just run that command.

Assuming you ran `ls -al /opt/ros/melodic/bin/roscore` and it tells you there is no such file or directory, it would seem for some reason you're missing the `roscore` binary.

You could try reinstalling it using:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ros-melodic-roslaunch
```

Pay close attention to the output of `apt`. Perhaps it tells you why it can't / couldn't install the `roslaunch` package successfully.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dean](https://answers.ros.org/users/53030/dean/) on 2020-03-31**:
Yes,I did so,but the same errors.

**Comment by [Dean](https://answers.ros.org/users/53030/dean/) on 2020-03-31**:
Must I reinstall ROS melodic?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-31**:
Let's not jump to conclusions.

Please tell us which command *exactly* you've used to install ROS (and where you found that command).

Then also tell us the output of `ls -al /opt/ros/melodic/bin/roscore`

**Comment by [Dean](https://answers.ros.org/users/53030/dean/) on 2020-03-31**:
There isn't roscore in /home/my name/opt/ros/melodic/bin,does it mean i didn't install successfully?

**Comment by [Dean](https://answers.ros.org/users/53030/dean/) on 2020-03-31**:
sudo apt install ros-melodic-desktop-full

**Comment by [Dean](https://answers.ros.org/users/53030/dean/) on 2020-03-31**:
http://wiki.ros.org/cn/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu

**Comment by [Dean](https://answers.ros.org/users/53030/dean/) on 2020-03-31**:
Why havn't roscore file? I see there is rosrun file.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-31**:
I'm not going to respond until you tell me the output of `ls -al /opt/ros/melodic/bin/roscore`.

**Comment by [Dean](https://answers.ros.org/users/53030/dean/) on 2020-03-31**:
ls: 无法访问'/opt/ros/melodic/bin/roscore': 没有那个文件或目录

It means : can't visit '/opt/ros/melodic/bin/roscore':there isn't that file or directory.

**Comment by [Dean](https://answers.ros.org/users/53030/dean/) on 2020-03-31**:
Thank you for lots.By your method:sudo apt install --reinstall ros-melodic-roslaunch,roscore does work.I can see the little cute tortoise and control it with arrow button.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-31**:
Good to hear you got it to work.

**Comment by [Dean](https://answers.ros.org/users/53030/dean/) on 2020-04-02**:
OK,thank you very much.You are great!